# QT CPP How to solve ambiguous error when calling function?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I have a function for write data with using serial port.I am using the send function on several pages. I have not encountered such a problem before, but when I try to use it again on the same page, I get an error. When I try call function again I got

```
error: call of overloaded 'send(const char [6])' is ambiguous
```

here is my header file

```
#ifndef SETDATETIME_H
#define SETDATETIME_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QTimer>
#include "serial.h"

namespace Ui {
class setdatetime;
}

class setdatetime : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit setdatetime(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~setdatetime();
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
public slots:


    void curtime();
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();


    void on_detailSaveBtn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::setdatetime *ui;
    QTimer *timer;
    Serial serialDateTime;
};

#endif // SETDATETIME_H
```

here is function I got error

```
void setdatetime::on_detailSaveBtn_clicked() {
    QSerialPortInfo info;
        QList<QSerialPortInfo> infoList = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();

           foreach(info, infoList) QTextStream(stdout) << info.portName();
        QString curport = info.portName();
  if (!serialDateTime.isOpen()) {

    if (serialDateTime.begin(QString(curport), 9600, 8, 0, 1, 0, false)) {
        serialDateTime.send("HELLO"); // call to member function 'send' is ambiguous
      serialDateTime.send(ui -> label -> text().toLatin1() + ui -> label_2 -> text().toLatin1()); //this working well

    }

  }
}

here is send function

bool Serial::send(QString message)
{
    if (this->serialDevice->isOpen() && this->serialDevice->isWritable())
    {
        this->serialDevice->write(message.toStdString().c_str());
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


bool Serial::send(const QByteArray &message)
{
    if (this->serialDevice->isOpen() && this->serialDevice->isWritable())
    {
        this->serialDevice->write(message);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: The problem I guess is that a `const char[6]` array can be converted to `QByteArray` and `QString`. The compiler does not know which function to use. You can use the `explicit` keyword to prohibit automatic conversion of types. Also your send methods have a lot of code duplication. Have the logic in only one method and let the other one call the one where you implemented the logic.

Comment: `serialDateTime.send(QString::fromUtf8("HELLO"))`

Answer (score 1):

There is many meaning that warning can take. In your case, is say that your string litteral `"HELLO"` is a `const char[6]` but can be implicitly converted to a `QByteArray` or a QString.

The problem is that your compiler doesn't like that and prefer to know explicitly what to do.

You can either use the `explicit` keyword to prohibit implicit casting, or pass directly a `QByteArray` OR a `QString` explicitly converted to make your compiler know that you want to use one definition or the other.

```cpp
serialDateTime.send(QByteArray::fromRawData("HELLO", 5)); // to call the QByteArray overload

serialDateTime.send(QString::fromUtf8("HELLO")); // to call the QString overload
```